# Can not ping google cloud sql

Tags: node.js, ip, ping, google-cloud-sql

So I am trying to see if my nodejs server can connect to my google cloud sql databse but its not working. I decided to ping the databse from my machine to see if any kind of connection would work.

My google cloud sql database has a IPv6 so i type this to ping it

```
ping 2001:4860:4864:1:b2ed:9ecb:9b6f:ab9c
```

But I get the response

```
Pinging 2001:4860:4864:1:b2ed:9ecb:9b6f:ab9c with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 2001:4860:4864:1:b2ed:9ecb:9b6f:ab9c:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I have added my IP address to the Allowed Networks so why cant I ping it or connect to it from my nodejs server?

Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ping to test connectivity to Cloud SQL. Due to the way that networking work within Cloud SQL the ping is not being sent to your instance. Pinging your instance's IP address tells you as much about it's status as if you pinged google.com.

Instead try simply making a TCP connection on port 3306. This is the only path that will allow you to externally connect to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling this option

```
no ipv6 nd suppress-ra
```

Comment: when I type in this to my nodejs console on google I get the error "-bash: no: command not found"
am I missing something, should I run the command somewhere else.

Comment: this would be typed in your cisco command line interface for your switch to make sure its not masking ipv6